# Access ViewModel Property in ko.utils.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a viewModel.

```
  var Vm = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.severityList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson('@Html.Raw(jsonData)'));
        self.deactivateSeverityLevel.bind(this);
    };
    ko.utils.extend(Vm.prototype, {
        deactivateSeverityLevel: function(item) {

        }
    });
```

I need to access the severityList inside the ko.utils.extend.
I try to add Vm.severityList inside the .extend but it's not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would access severity list using `this.severityList` inside of `deactivateSeverityLevel`.

Depending on where you call it from, you may need to use `bind` to ensure that `this` is correct.

If you are binding it within its own scope, then you are fine without a `bind` call like:

```
<button data-bind="click: deactivateSeverityLevel">Deactive</button>
```

If you are binding to a different scope (like `$parent`), then you would need to `bind` it. You could either do:

```
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.deactivateSeverityLevel.bind($parent)">Deactive</button>
```

or:

```
var Vm = function() {
    this.severityList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson('@Html.Raw(jsonData)'));
    this.deactivateSeverityLevel = this.deactivateSeverityLevel.bind(this);
};

ko.utils.extend(Vm.prototype, {
    deactivateSeverityLevel: function(item) {
        //access this.severityList()
    }
});
```

In this last example, you are creating a bound version of the `deactivateSeverityLevel` function on the instance by binding the implementation from the prototype the current value of `this`.

Comment: Why not just declare and bind the deactiveSeverityLevel function in the constructor.  You are losing all the benefits of declaring it on the prototype when you copy the method from the prototype to the instance

Comment: @RobertSlaney - it is not ideal to bind in that way, but the implementation of the function will still only be defined once on the prototype with each instance having a wrapper to it bound to the current instance. So, the benefit is less than just having it defined on the prototype, but the actual implementation of the function is only defined once still.

Comment: I hadn't thought about this approach... I like it.  Gives me a idea for an extension of my Javascript Dependency Injection library to automatically bind all prototype methods when the objects are constructed!